# UITableview crashes when scrolling down while adding new row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, afnetworking

When I'm at the bottom of my UITableView I reload new data via JSON and add 10 new rows to the existing UITableView. It works fine, unless I'm scrolling down exactly at the moment when the new row gets added. Then I get the error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to create two animations for cell'

I'm loading my data like this:

```
- (void) retrieveMoreData {
        //My URL stuff
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

        [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            //do some stuff
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

Is beginUpdates, endUpdates somehow animated? Or are the rows I want to insert animated? If yes - how can I prevent that?

Comment: 1) You don't need to use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` if you only make one call to update the table. 2) You must update the table view on the main thread, not a background thread. That's the most likely cause of your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy the `AFNetworking` handler blocks are called on main, so it's most likely not that.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for your help. I think I need beginUpdates and endUpdates, when I remove it I get this error: 'attempt to insert row 10 into section 0, but there are only 10 rows in section 0 after the update' I'm adding 10 rows there with insertrowsatindexpaths.

Comment: You get that error because you need to update your data model before updating the table view.

Comment: @Dima Thanks. My bad for assuming the completion handler was called on another thread.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm adding 10 rows with [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; and because I call this 10 times I need beginupdates and endupdates or is this incorrect? I update my data model, thats not the problem. The new 10 rows load fine when I dont scroll down while loading. But when I scroll down right at the time the row gets added it crashes :/